# Creating a Larvel method like view() to import other files

Tags: php, laravel-8

As the title says, I need to create a method in Laravel that works like view('name'), but includes files from another folder.

What's the best way to do this without altering Laravel's core functionality?

I was thinking maybe of extending the functionality but I do not have enough Laravel knowledge to know what's the best place to write the function in and/or the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created an external .php file that I've included in Laravel's index with the functionality that I need, and it was usable in the .blade.php files as well.